# WooCommerce Slider Info Needed Flexslider

Tags: woocommerce, flexslider

Does the latest WooCommerce use Flexslider?

I am using WooCommerce version 3.0.2  - for slider on single products does it use Flexslider?

https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/

I am trying to make a customisation but it is not having luck, 
 PLease let me know,

Cheers,
Ben.

Comment: the answer is: yes, it does :)
https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/1f66a294576525e662c8182b25ab68ac41d2d4a6/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php#L181

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download and integrate the flexslider.